# Automatically loading HDFS Configuration based on HADOOP_HOME?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am working on a Java program to interface with an already running hadoop cluster. The program has `HADOOP_HOME` passed to it as an environment variable.

Based on this value, I need to load all of the necessary configuration resources before I start interacting with HDFS/MapReduce. The files that I think I need are based on the [apache documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/cluster_setup.html#Configuration+Files). My current solution looks like this:

```
final String HADOOP_HOME = System.getEnv("HADOOP_HOME");
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "src/core/core-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "src/hdfs/hdfs-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "src/mapred/mapred-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "conf/mapred-site.xml"));

FileSystem hdfs = new FileSystem(conf);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Hopefully a way that does not involve setting each resource explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run your jar using `hadoop jar <your-jar>`.  This sets up everything automatically.

Comment: But this means I'm running my code as an hadoop map reduce job isn't so? What is the effect of that?

Comment: Do u have an answer? I need to execute a jar (not a map reduce job) and load the configuration.

Comment: Just running Hadoop jar doesn't make it a mapreduce job. Hadoop jar sets up the environment, what you do inside your jar is up to you.