# Access HDFS from Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I installed Hadoop locally on my Mac using `brew`. It's accessible via the web UI (localhost:50070), and when I run commands e.g. `hdfs dfs -ls /`, `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal`, etc...

I'm having problems getting Java to read from HDFS. I tried the following, based on another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200749/automatically-loading-hdfs-configuration-based-on-hadoop-home%20%22another%20StackOverflow%20question%22.):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

[...]

final String HADOOP_HOME = System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME");
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(HADOOP_HOME, "libexec/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"));

FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

hdfs.createNewFile(new Path("/should_be_in_the_root_of_hdfs"));
```

When I run this, I can see that the new file is created in the local filesystem rather than HDFS. Can you see what needs to be changed in order to interact with HDFS?

Comment: open your core-site.xml and check property fs.default.name has hdfs:// or file:///

Comment: A great suggestion, thanks @bl3e. core-site.xml has a single property: `<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value></property>`. Although `core-default.xml` has the `fs.default.name` property set to `file:///`, the comments in the description note that this property has been deprecated, and we should now use `fs.defaultFS`.

Comment: I was also able to confirm this using `getconf`: Both `$ hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS` and `$ hdfs getconf -confKey fs.default.name` return `hdfs://localhost:9000`.

Comment: btw if you use hadoop -jar to run you don't need to add any of these resources.If you are running differently then try by adding only core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml,remove other lines